# Xamarin Studio creates files with wrong namespace

Tags: ios, namespaces, xamarin, mvvmcross, keynotfoundexception

i'm currently using Xamarin Studio and i'm developing an app with the MvvmCross framework.

My issue is that, when I try to create a new file in my folder named "Views", the namespace does not contain the ".Views".

I have Xamarin.Client.iOS instead of Xamarin.Client.iOS.Views. So the MvvmCross framework doesn't find my views and return a `KeyNotFoundException : could not find view for [MyViewModel]`

I wonder if XCode modified my namespaces because my app worked well and now it can't find the views.

I guess it's a namespace problem but not really sure. The fact is my "View" files are not in the ".Views" namespace while they are in the "Views" folder.

How can I create my Views with the good namespace ? Because changing it in the .cs and .designer.cs file does not fix the KeyNotFoundException...

If you have any idea...

Comment: I would doubt that the `KeyNotFoundException` was caused by the wrong namespace - it's more likely to be caused by wrong base class, missing constructor or some other problem. If something changed, is there any way you can identify what it was - e.g. looking over a source control diff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio, Preferences --> Source Code --> .NET Naming Policies

Check "Associate namespaces with directory names" if you want your classes to include the folder name in the namespace by default.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was driving me nuts, especially with auto-generated .resx files.